# typo3 extension activation is not possible

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

Hi I try to install a new TYPO3 8.7 version on a new server.

When I installed TYPO3 all looks good. But I can't aktivate Extensions. It dosn't mather if it is my own extension or a third party extension or a core extension.

I don't got an error. the extension is activated in extension manager. But the extension is not listed and can't be used.

What is the issue in this case?

Thanks in advance.

They are not shown there, but its activated in extension manager.
[image]

Comment: "Not listed" you mean in backend content-element of type 'list', where you can choose any frontend-plugin? Could you then check backend-modul 'Configuration' $GLOBALS[TCA][tt_content][columns][list_type][config][items]? Maybe it got overriden by any configuration.

Comment: updated my answer above

Comment: Not every activated extension is listed there. Help> About for example installs a couple of items (About TYPO3 CMS and About modules) in the Help module in the top bar (the ? in a circle icon on the top bar)

Comment: Help was just an example. no extension is listetd after activation.

Comment: files like /typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php and /typo3conf/PackageStates.php are writable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved.

update extensions in view "get extensions" does the trick